# CSS Dropdown menu offset in Internet Explorer, other artifacts too

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I built a dropdown menu for a clients site using just css, and it looks great in chrome. Of course, I didn't check it in IE before allowing the client to use the site and of course the client uses IE. Anyways, here are two screenshots. The first one is chrome, and is what I want it to look like:

http://addproxy.net/sites/testing_space/chrome.jpg
http://addproxy.net/sites/testing_space/ie.jpg

And here is the CSS I used for the ENTIRE nav bar, because I have a feeling that one of my styles from the standard nav bar are causing the dropdown to look funny:

```
/* home (navigation) */
#nav{
    background-image:url(images/nav_bg.png);
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    width:940px;
    height:42px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:-1px 0 0 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #a61300;
    z-index:5;
}
#nav #language{
    font-size:10px;
    float:right;
}
#nav ul li{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#nav ul li a{
    display:block;
}
/*fancy nav */
#nav ul li ul a{
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
}
#nav ul li ul {
     display:none;
     padding:10px 0;
     text-align:center;
     width:160px;
     background:#b83423;
     border:1px solid #a61300;
     margin:10px 0 0 -14px;
     z-index:10;
}
#nav ul li #esp {
    width:200px;
}
#nav ul li ul li{
    border:0;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:10;
}
/*end fancy nav */
#nav a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}
#nav p{
    position:relative;
    display:inline;
}
#nav a:active{
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#links{
    margin:0 0 0 10px;
}
#links li{
    display:inline;
    padding:12px 13px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#links li{
    border-right:1px solid #a61300;
}
#links a:hover{
    color:#ddd;
}
#links a:last-child{
    border:0;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div id="nav">
    <ul id="links">
        <a href="http://conceptoservices.com/?page_id=10"><li>Home</li></a>
        <a href="http://conceptoservices.com/?page_id=13"><li>About Us</li></a>
        <a href="http://conceptoservices.com/?page_id=16"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Services
            <ul>
                <a href="http://conceptoservices.com/?page_id=21"><li>Business Services</li></a>
                <a href="http://conceptoservices.com/?page_id=23"><li>Notary Services</li></a>
                <a href="http://conceptoservices.com/?page_id=25"><li>Other Services</li></a>
            </ul>
        </li></a>
        <a href="http://conceptoservices.com/?page_id=27"><li>ITIN</li></a>
        <a href="http://conceptoservices.com/?page_id=29">
        <li id="language">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/esp.png" />
        </li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This community never lets me down. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the HTML as well please?

Comment: Have you done a 'CSS reset' to make sure all browsers start off with the same margins, padding, etc?

Comment: your <a> tags should be INSIDE the <li>tags.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've not seen the HTML, but I've written some of my own with guesswork. Curiously, the IE issues I get with that are totally different, but nevertheless, try this. It helped a whole bunch on every version of IE:

```
#nav ul li ul li { display: block; float: none;}
```

If that still doesn't work, you could try adding clear: left and see what that does.

*Edit:* By the way, here's the HTML I used:

```
<div id="nav" style="background: #666">
            <ul id="links">
                <li><a href="giff">Guff</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="abc">Guff 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="def">Guff 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                        <li><a href="ghi">Guff</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="jkl">Guff 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="mno">Guff 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting! I had no luck however. Actually, nothing happened. I tried: #nav ul li ul li { display: block; float: none;} and #nav ul li ul li { display: block; float: none; clear:left;}

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell how you're positioning that submenu so my money is on that. Try positioning it absolutely relative to your menu items, like so:

```
#nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 160px;
    background: #B83423;
    border: 1px solid #A61300;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 25px;
}
```

Here is a demo that works in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/5faH4/show/

---

By the way, another user pointed me towards your positioning on your submenu upon `:hover`, that is wrong, you have to position your submenu on a higher level and not on an event. My answer above takes care of that.

Comment: He/she's positioning it absolutely, but only on hover.

Comment: @p.g.l.hall ahh, saw it, thats wrong, he's should be positioning it on a higher level and not on an event.

Comment: Thank you for the post, the problem had nothing to do with positioning but your response did help me figure it out. It was simple. I was doing <a><li></li></a>, your jsfiddle was <li><a></a></li>! Changing the order fixed everything.

Comment: @user1036734 Just noticed that, did not check your edit for the html :P